# Can I attack crawlers with melee weapons without (definitely) being hit?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I'd expect, from the many depictions of zombies by which I have been victimized, that *crawlers* would pose little danger as long as I'm aware of them and don't stand too close. I'd think that, in 7DTD, I (my character) should be able to easily dispatch a crawler. A swift blow to the head, easily made from my greater height and, assuming I'm holding a suitable mêlée weapon, with my much longer reach, should be relatively riskless. Instead, I find crawlers to be *more* dangerous than 'walkers'!

Perhaps crawlers greater danger lies (ha) in their means of locomotion (flailing their arms) also serving as attacks. Or maybe I'm just getting too close and I should try attacking from a greater distance.

Is there something I'm missing? Or are crawlers really as dangerous as they now seem to me to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

I was relying on my visual perception of how close I was to zombies to decide when to attack. I didn't think to actually *test* the maximum distance from which I could land an attack. Having now done that, I learned that all zombies, crawlers too, can be attacked from what *looks* like an impossible-to-reach distance.

Comment: The [range](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Range) of most melee weapons is the same, a little over 2 blocks. The tactic I use is to start swinging, run into range, land the blow, and then run backwards before they can retaliate.